# Row level sum of values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

I have a SQL data as

```
BugID  Request Date  Closed Date
--------------------------------
1234   11/1/2013     11/5/2013
2345   11/1/2013     11/2/2013
2435   11/2/2013     11/2/2013
6345   11/3/2013     11/5/2013
9364   11/5/2013     11/6/2013
```

I want the results to be

```
Date       Requested Bugs  Closed Bugs  Total Open  Total Closed
----------------------------------------------------------------
11/1/2013  2               0            2           0
11/2/2013  1               2            3           2
11/3/2013  1               0            4           2
11/5/2013  1               1            5           3
11/6/2013  0               1            5           4
```

Is it possible via Transact SQL?

Comment: Did you try anything? How you get the *Total Open*? Is the date value null for the open ones?

Comment: you can use `COUNT(column_name)` to get the number of records. something like `SELECT COUNT(BugId) FROM your_table`. The count function will give the number of non null columns which satisfy the condition.  [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) . Something to get you started with.

Comment: Which SQL Server version ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
with allDates (date) as
(
    select requestDate from dbo.bugs
    union select closedDate from dbo.bugs
)
select date,
    (select count(*) from dbo.bugs where requestDate = a.date) as bugsRequested,
    (select count(*) from dbo.bugs where closedDate = a.date) as bugsClosed,
    (select count(*) from dbo.bugs where a.date between requestDate and closedDate) AS bugsOpen,
    (select count(*) from dbo.bugs where closedDate<=a.date) AS totalClosed
from allDates a
```

Live example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/de05f/15

Comment: It's best to avoid the use of [BETWEEN with date/time/timestamps in SQL Server](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  Especially as we don't know the version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

you could use CASE statement inside your SUM/COUNT function something like this

```
SELECT   CAST([Request Date] AS DATE) AS [Request Date]
       , COUNT(*) AS [Requested Bugs]
       , COUNT(CASE WHEN [Closed Date] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [Closed Bugs]
       , COUNT(CASE WHEN [Closed Date] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [Total Open]
FROM Table_Name 
GROUP BY CAST([Request Date] AS DATE)
```

I have considered a Closed colum here which will indicate which jobs are still open, it could be a bit field or anything else, but the main idea is to show you how you can make use of CASE statement inside an aggregate function to only count certain rows.

Comment: @huMptyduMpty yep should work, why do you see anything wrong with it please feel free to edit my post I dont mind it at all :)

Comment: @M.Ali: Not correct. If you haven't opened task in a day but you have closed task you don't count them.

Comment: @M.Ali: It should be something like `CASE WHEN ...`

Comment: @JoeTaras it will be counted on the date you will close it. and it should be counted only on that date not the date it was opened.

Comment: @M.Ali: Exactly. If you have opened a task on 2013.12.08 and you'll close on 2013.12.15 you must have two rows. The first with first counter = 1 and the second with second counter = 1. In your case you have only one row.